# How to automate source control with Oracle database

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c

I work in an Oracle instance that has hundreds of schemas and multiple developers. We have a development instance where developers can integrate their work before test or production.

We want to have source control for all the DDL run in this integrated development database. Currently this is done through a product Red Gate which we run manually after we make a change to the database. Redgate finds the changes between what is in the schema and what was last checked into source control and makes a script of the differences and puts this into source control.

The problem however is of course that running regdate can take some time and people run it infrequently or not at all for small changes. Also redgate will only look in one schema at a time and it would be VERY time consuming to manually run it against all schemas to guarantee that they are up to date. However if the source controlled code cannot be relied upon it becomes less useful...

What would seem to be ideal would be to have some software that could periodically (even once a day), or when triggered by DDL being run, update the source control (preferably github as this is used by other teams) from all the schemas.

I cannot seem to see any existing software which can be simply used to do this.

Is there a problem with doing this? (there is no need to address multiple developers overwriting each others work on the same day as we have this covered in a separate process) Is anyone doing this?  Can anyone recommend a way to do this?

Comment: *Red-Gate* is a **company** - not a product - so what product from Red-Gate Software **exactly** are you using?

Comment: Are you generating SQL scripts automatically with a tool and then saving those generated scripts into version control ?

Comment: user272735 - Yes the product from redgate (I'll have to check its name when I"m at work) generates the scripts of changes made to the database and then puts the scripts into version control.

Comment: The red-gate product is called 'Source Control'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We do this with help of a PL/SQL function, a python script and a shell script:

- The PL/SQL function can generate the DDL of a whole schema and returns this as CLOB
- The python script connects to the database, fetches the DDL and stores it in files
- The shell script runs the Source Control to add the modifications (we use Bazaar here).

You can see the scripts on PasteBin:

- The PL/SQL function is here: http://pastebin.com/AG2Fa9zL
- The python program (schema_exporter.py): http://pastebin.com/nd8Lf0gK
- The shell script:

The shell script:

```
python schema_exporter.py
d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d__%H_%M_%S)
bzr add
bzr st | grep -q -E 'added|modified' &&  commit -m "Database objects on $d"
exit 0
```

This shell script is configured to run from cron every day.

Comment: That's very similar to what we do. In our case, it's a nightly cron job that runs a Ruby script, generates one file per object and commits that to our Mercurial repo.

Answer (score 3):

Being in the database version control space for 5 years (as director of product management at [DBmaestro](http://www2.dbmaestro.com/l/11742/2014-12-31/2grnfp)) and having worked as a DBA for over two decades, I can tell you the simple fact that you cannot treat the database objects as you treat your Java, C# or other files and save the changes in simple DDL scripts.

There are many reasons and I'll name a few:

- Files are stored locally on the developer’s PC and the change s/he
  makes do not affect other developers. Likewise, the developer is not
  affected by changes made by her colleague. In database this is
  (usually) not the case and developers share the same database
  environment, so any change that were committed to the database affect
  others.
- Publishing code changes is done using the Check-In / Submit Changes /
  etc. (depending on which source control tool you use). At that point,
  the code from the local directory of the developer is inserted into
  the source control repository. Developer who wants to get the latest
  code need to request it from the source control tool. In database the
  change already exists and impacts other data even if it was not
  checked-in into the repository.
- During the file check-in, the source control tool performs a conflict
  check to see if the same file was modified and checked-in by another
  developer during the time you modified your local copy. Again there
  is no check for this in the database. If you alter a procedure from
  your local PC and at the same time I modify the same procedure with
  code form my local PC then we override each other’s changes.
- The build process of code is done by getting the label / latest
  version of the code to an empty directory and then perform a build –
  compile. The output are binaries in which we copy & replace the
  existing. We don't care what was before. In database we cannot
  recreate the database as we need to maintain the data! Also the
  deployment executes SQL scripts which were generated in the build
  process.
- When executing the SQL scripts (with the DDL, DCL, DML (for static
  content) commands) you assume the current structure of the
  environment match the structure when you create the scripts. If not,
  then your scripts can fail as you are trying to add new column which
  already exists.
- Treating SQL scripts as code and manually generating them will cause
  syntax errors, database dependencies errors, scripts that are not
  reusable which complicate the task of developing, maintaining,
  testing those scripts. In addition, those scripts may run on an
  environment which is different from the one you though it would run
  on.
- Sometimes the script in the version control repository does not match
  the structure of the object that was tested and then errors will
  happen in production!

There are many more, but I think you got the picture.

What I found that works is the following:

1. Use an enforced version control system that enforces
   check-out/check-in operations on the database objects. This will
   make sure the version control repository matches the code that was
   checked-in as it reads the metadata of the object in the check-in
   operation and not as a separated step done manually. This also allow
   several developers to work in parallel on the same database while
   preventing them to accidently override each other code.
2. Use an impact analysis that utilize baselines as part of the
   comparison to identify conflicts and identify if a difference (when
   comparing the object's structure between the source control
   repository and the database) is a real change that origin from
   development or a difference that was origin from a different path and
   then it should be skipped, such as different branch or an emergency
   fix.
3. Use a solution that knows how to perform Impact Analysis for many
   schemas at once, using UI or using API in order to eventually
   automate the build & deploy process.

An article I wrote on this was published [here](http://www2.dbmaestro.com/l/11742/2014-12-31/2grnfr), you are welcome to read it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm interested in reading the article.  I cannot access it at that URI or submit my details on the form.  I'll try again later.

Answer (score 3):

To me it seems like your way of working is backwards: developers run DDL against the DB in an unordered fashion and then you need an automated tool for inferring the changes (and the DDL) that was run.

The process would be in better control if you did the following instead:

- Developers write DDL as SQL scripts, preferably using a migration tool such as Flyway (http://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/sql.html).
- Migration scripts are checked into version control
- Migration scripts are periodically run against the DB (e.g. by the migration tool)

In this workflow, the DB would only get altered through automated migration scripts and no-one is allowed to do changes manually. Could this work for you?

Comment: It sounds ideal, however some of our databases are often developed against directly as such we need to be able to run DDL in an unordered fashion to check procedures compile correctly etc.  It maybe a flaw in our environment (I say maybe as it does save a lot of time not to do this) but its not something I'm going to be able to change overnight.

Answer (score 2):

(I develop the Oracle tools for Redgate)
Actually using the tools you can already what I think you're asking for using Schema Compare for Oracle.

You can compare multiple schemas either in the UI or via the command line - I think what you're after is automating the command line tool which can create difference scripts, sync between source and destination (live, snapshot or scripts) and generate reports.

You can automate the command line to sync to a scripts folder which is your source code checkout and then subsequently run a command to commit the changes.

I think that's all good :)

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I did look into this but couldn't see how to go about it.  In any case we have our red gate source control tool installed on our PCs - I think for us using the pl/sql/python/batch file will allow it to run from a server when PCs are turned off and retired etc so its probably best for us.  (I suspect it means we don't pay an annual fee to red gate too which is nice)

Comment: Fair enough. For future reference the full command line documentation is available at http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SCO3/Command+line+switches

Answer (score -1):

We built a commerical tool that bridges Oracle with Git. It helps you manage your database objects with Git. Basically, the database becomes the working directory for the developer. You can perform git operations in the database such as reset, commit, branch, merge etc... and the database code is updated automatically. It might be worth taking a look: https://www.gitora.com